# IOS Swift 2 - How to construct multidimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I achieve the following output:

```
rsPool[0][p1] = "123"
rsPool[0][p2] = "234"
rsPool[1][p1] = "abc"
rsPool[1][p2] = "bcd"
```

I deserialized from JSON output, which has the following data

```
first dimention > type (1 to 7)
second dimention > p1...P10
value > xxxx
```

I have tried to create:

```
var rspool : [Int: String] : []
```

but I don't know how to add/append to the array.

Comment: Don't append to an array if you're using static data. Initialize it directly with a literal expression, like @sasquatch showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define multidimensional array by use square brackets multiple times:

```
var rspool: [[String]] = [["123", "234"], ["abc", "bcd"]]
print(rspool[0][0])
print(rspool[0][1])
print(rspool[1][0])
print(rspool[1][1])
//123
//234
//abc
//bcd
```

This is array of arrays of `String`.

**Dynamic array**

Usually you use dynamically changed array sizes, by using `Array` methods like `append`, `insert` and `removeAtIndex`. Lets compose given array from empty array:

```
var rspool = [[String]]()

rspool.append([String]()) //adding first line; now we can access it by rspool[0]
rspool[0].append("abc")
rspool[0].append("bcd")

//we started from second line for to show example with insert:
rspool.insert([String](), atIndex: 0) //inserting new line as first line
rspool[0].append("123")
rspool[0].append("234")
print(rspool)
//[["123", "234"], ["abc", "bcd"]]
```

You need always be careful with accessing to this array by indexes, since you can receive "index out of range" exception. You read and overwrite *existed* values in array directly by indexes:

```
let veryFirst = raspol[0][0]
raspol[0][0] = "456"
```

---

**Static array**

If you wish manipulate your array only by indexes, aka matrix style, you need to set constant dimensions and initialize all array first. `Optional` type as element type and repeated values are useful then:

```
let m = 3
let n = 5
var rspool = [[String?]](count: m, repeatedValue: [String?](count: n, repeatedValue: nil))
```

Now you can read an write elements by indexes:

```
rspool[0][0] = "123"
rspool[0][1] = "234"
rspool[1][0] = "abc"
rspool[1][1] = "bcd"
print(rspool)
//[[Optional("123"), Optional("234"), nil, nil, nil], [Optional("abc"), Optional("bcd"), nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Matrix- style array numerating example:

```
rspool[2][4] = "END"
for i in 0..<m {
    for j in 0..<n {
        print("\(rspool[i][j] ?? ".")\t", terminator: "")
    }
    print()
}
//123 234 .   .   .
//abc bcd .   .   .
//.   .   .   .   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be this:

```
var rsPool = [
    [
        "p1": "123",
        "p2": "234"
    ],
    [
        "p1": "abc",
        "p2": "bcd"
    ]
]
```

which is of type `[Dictionary<String, String>]`

So the declaration should be:

```
var rsPool: [[String:String]]
```

Here's Playground reference:
[image: play]

Comment: error: **Array index out of range** when I try to set the : `rspool[0]["p1"] = "123"`